# AEROSPIKE_ERR_INDEX_NOT_FOUND - Python Client

Tags: aerospike

The data is pulled from BigQuery, and we're certain that the interval exist.

Codes used:

```py
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

query = client.query('test', 'demo')

query.select('pickup', 'passenger_count')

# query.where(p.between('passenger_count',1,3))


def print_result(args):
    key, metadata, record = args
    print(record)

query.foreach(print_result)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using aql, create a secondary index, once. $ aql ==> aql> CREATE INDEX idx_p_count on test.demo (passenger_count) numeric  ==> then run your code, should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means you do not have a secondary index defined for 'passenger_count'. Learn more here: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity/secondary_indexes.html.